# html2canvas renders fixed element in wrong position

Tags: html2canvas

When I use html2canvas on a page with a fixed header, it renders the header near the bottom of the canvas rather than where it should be at the top.  Is there a workaround for this so that it renders fixed elements in the correct position?

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is possible that you need to specify the [vertical-align property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) of the header's children elements to be `text-top`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting scrollX and scrollY to 0 sorted the issue.

```
 html2canvas(document.body,{scrollX: 0, scrollY: 0})
```